# JSON object not refreshed after updates (cross-domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to request JSON document from another domain, and it works.

But, my main problem is that JSON is not updating the objects after updates.

Here's my **Previous/Before updates** JSON Data.

```
{
    "name": "human",
    "version": "1.0",
    "list": [
        {"name": "Human1", "blood": "A"}
    ]
}
```

This is my **AJAX Function**

```
function getHumans () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        url: "https://some.website/file.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);        
        }
    });
};
```

First request was perfectly fine, with output:

```
{name: "human", version: "1.0", list: Array(1)}
```

And then, I'm trying to add another object on `list` array. So, the Array should be (2), but it's not. the Array still (1), I also turned off my cache, but did not work.

I want the JSON to automatically update/refresh the objects, without reloading or refreshing the page. I use this on **Electron**.

Comment: _And then, i trying to add another object on list array_ May be it is not added in first place ?

Comment: Once Try in the incognito window.

Comment: _not added in first place_?, i already _add/insert(?)_ new object after `array[0]` with this `{"name": "Human2", "blood": "A"}` and of course with comma.

Comment: @nitishk72 i use electron. Oh wait, can i use incognito on electron tho?

Comment: To prevent caching send a dummy parameter which changes. ` data: {
      time: (new Date().getTime())
   },`

Comment: Can you add part of code were you are adding elements to object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use .push() to add elements. Let's suppose:

```
a = {name: "human", version: "1.0", list: [1]}

a.list.push(2);
```

results in:

```
{name: "human", version: "1.0", list: [1,2]}
```

if your new **list** element comes from data:

```
a.list.push(data.list[0]); //or similar
```

If you want to replace the whole list array, then:

```
a.list = data.list;
```

Keep in mind that var `a` in this case is needed to live out of the context of your getHumans() function so, each time you call getHumans() that function must update the value of `a`, you could pass the variables as a parameter or perform something like  `a =  getHumans()` where getHumans() return the new value of a.

Comment: Thank you, it's solved. but how about removing the array? should i use `.push()` tho?

Comment: it depends. If you want to keep the type array of `list` (I think is the best approach) you could do something `like a.list = []`